# How to show placeholder in <select2> tag in angular 4?

Tags: angular, jquery-select2, placeholder

My HTML code is,

```
<select2 [value]="student" (valueChanged)="studentvaluechanged($event)" [data]="data.getStudentList()"id="student" name="student" 
placeholder="Student Name*">
</select2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. After adding `[options]="{ placeholder: 'Student Name*' }"`, it's working now.

```
<select2 [value]="student" (valueChanged)="studentvaluechanged($event)" [data]="data.getStudentList()"id="student" name="student" 
[options]="{ placeholder: 'Student Name*' }">
</select2>
```

Answer (score -1):

With jquery

```
   $("#student").select2({
        placeholder: "Student Name*",
        allowClear: true
    });
```

Or you can try

```
<select2 [value]="student" (valueChanged)="studentvaluechanged($event)" [data]="data.getStudentList()"id="student" name="student">Student Name*</select2>
```